# What is the simplest way to send data to a script after a certain action is completed?

Tags: php, post, get, data-transfer

I am building a script that will handle data that is sent to it. This data will be in the form of `id=xyz` and `key=j9ofi902f89djs8if` with `id` and `key` particular to each script that is sending the data to my script. I am trying to think of a fool proof way that would make it exceedingly simple for anyone who wants to send this data to my script to do it.

My handling script will be built in PHP. The scripts sending the data to it will not be on the same domain. The data needs to be sent after a certain button is pressed the sending page and the form is verified that it has no errors. I would like to be able to control the process of sending and receiving all myself, but I cannot think of a way to do that. Is there a way to do this that would work across the board?

If not, what would be the best way to make it so that each different sending script that uses their own language, and method can easily send it to my script. Would a POST or a GET or something else be better. I want to make it so that they can send the data in the middle of their handling the form and on the script proceed to do other things after they send me the data. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AJAX, send the data through AJAX without a page refresh or a page redirect that is done with the post option. I think it is the best solution for your application.

[Ajax tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp).

Comment: AJAX is always the best solution.

Comment: true... and I am not eliminating that option, but I am trying to give my users the option and am trying to see if there is a good method that covers all the options.

Comment: I think AJAX covers all your options, you can get the response too from the script, and can update the page live as the user is filling/modifying the form.

Comment: If you want the sending page to send some data in the middle of form-filling you can't do it without Ajax, without it a form does nothing until submitted.

Comment: I want to give my users the option to let people fill out the form and then they verify the form is filled out correctly preferably with Ajax, but some websites still prefer to use form that handles itself so in those cases I want them to be able to send me the data after the form handle's itself.